# Typescripts Strict Null Checking and Observable Filters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I would expect that value.length to be always defined by the time it reaches the .map operator. But using strictNullChecks with typescript throws the error "Object is possibly 'undefined'." Am I wrong, or is this a known issue?

```
this.count$ = this.store.select<Model>('state')
            .filter(value => !!value && !!value.prop)
            .map(value => value.prop)
```

Answer (score 2):

It would only be defined if you provide some sort of initial value in your NGRX reducer.  It can potentially be undefined if you haven't done that.

If you are dealing with arrays, then you want to set your initial value to `[]`:

```
const initialState = [];

export function myReducer(state = initialState, action: Action)
....
```

The TypeScript compiler is correct, you could potentially have an undefined value if you haven't defined something somewhere.

**EDIT**

I think you are right in that the compiler isn't accurately detecting null values.  If I turn on `strictNullChecks` and do the following, it works fine:

```
arr: Person[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.arr
    .filter(x => !!x && !!x.firstName)
    .map(x => console.log(x.firstName));
}
```

In fact, if I remove the `filter`, it still compiles without error.  If I add `this.arr.push(<Person>{lastName: 'test'});` it still compiles without error even though I never defined `firstName` on the object and thus it will be undefined.

If I remove the signature on `arr` then I get compiler errors that `x.firstName` is not defined.:

```
  arr = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arr
      .filter(x => !!x && !!x.firstName)
      .map(x => console.log(x.firstName));
  }
```

So the TypeScript compiler with `strictNullChecks` checks whether fields exist on an object interface, but not necessarily whether they are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But surely it would never get to 'map(value => value.prop)' where the error is being reported because of the filter

Comment: One would think.  It could also be effected by the fact you are using a string selector on your ngrx store.  Try interface hardcoding by using `this.store.select(s => s.state)` instead.  This way the compiler correctly infers the data type from the store instead of your cast with `<Model>`.

Comment: No luck unfortunately ... :(